# Interceptação de Exception para logging, utilizando AOP com CDI em Java EE 7

Tags: exceção, log, cdi, java-ee-7, aop

Abaixo eu tenho parte de uma classe, da qual quero eliminar o código repetitivo de logging através de AOP.

```
/**
 * Javadoc omitido
 */
public abstract class JpaDao<T extends LongIdentifiable> implements
        GenericDao<T> { 

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Long persist(T type) throws GeneralPersistenceException {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException("Can't persist null");
        }

        try {
            entityManager.persist(type);
            return type.getId();
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            String message = "Failed to persist an entity";
            logger.error(message, e);
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException(message, e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public T merge(T type) throws GeneralPersistenceException {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException("Can't merge null");
        }

        try {
            T mergedType = entityManager.merge(type);
            return mergedType;
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            String message = "Failed to merge an entity";
            logger.error(message, e);
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException(message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Observem que o seguinte trecho de código é bem repetitivo nos métodos `persist` e `merge`, além de que eu acredite que a escrita de log pode ser tratada em outro lugar:

```
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    String message = "Failed to persist an entity";
    logger.error(message, e);
    throw new GeneralPersistenceException(message, e);
}
```

O código candidato para substituir o trecho acima é o abaixo:

```
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    throw new GeneralPersistenceException("Failed to persist an entity", e);
}
```

Em outras palavras, eu gostaria de que toda vez que uma `GeneralPersistenceException` fosse lançada, uma mensagem de log fosse gravada. Abaixo está a minha Exception:

```
public class GeneralPersistenceException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6057737927996676949L;

    public GeneralPersistenceException() {
    }

    public GeneralPersistenceException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public GeneralPersistenceException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public GeneralPersistenceException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Como vocês podem observar, ela só possui construtores.
Dado essa premissa, tenho as seguintes dúvidas:

1. A melhor estratégia para resolver o problema em uma aplicação Java EE 7, é o AOP com CDI?
2. Caso seja AOP, devo interceptar a `GeneralPersistenceException`?
3. É possível interceptar os construtores da `GeneralPersistenceException`, ou somente métodos (os quais ainda não existem)?
4. Já existe algo pronto para isso e estou reinventando a roda?